# Wrong charset when scraping with Scraperjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, character-encoding, web-scraping

I'm currently scraping a website with charset ISO-8859-1 using Scraperjs. My problem is that characters such as æ, ø, å and é are not properly encoded (they are displayed/saved as a question mark).

Any ideas?

Scraperjs:
https://github.com/ruipgil/scraperjs

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself. You need to specify the encoding to binary in order to read the characters as displayed. See code below:

```
        scraperjs.StaticScraper.create()
        .request({ url:"http://vg.no", encoding: "binary"})
        .scrape(function($) {
            return $("p").map(function() {
                return $(this);
            });
        })
        .then(function(domElements).........
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const scraperjs = require('scraperjs');
const urlToScrape = 'http://www.somesite.com';
const selectorToScrape = "div#someId";
scraperjs.StaticScraper.create({
    url: urlToScrape, 
    encoding: "binary"
}).scrape(function ($) {
    return $(selectorToScrape).map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
}).then(function (result) {
 console.log(result);
});
```